# Bitmap region is already locked

Tags: c#, bitmap, invalidoperationexception

```
string pathFile = @"C:\Users\user\Downloads\CaptchaCollection\Small\Sorted\";

var files = Directory.GetFiles(pathFile).Select(nameWithExtension => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nameWithExtension)).Where(name => { int number; return int.TryParse(name, out number); }).Select(name => int.Parse(name)).OrderBy(number => number).ToArray();
List<int> fileList = files.ToList();

image1 = new Bitmap(pathFile + fileList[0].ToString() + ".png");
image2 = new Bitmap(pathFile + fileList[1].ToString() + ".png");

if (compare(image2, image2))
{
    // if it's equal
    File.Delete(image2.ToString());
}
```

So basically what I have right now is that every file is numeric (without extension). I created an array then converted it to a list.

I use my global variables `image1` and `image2` which are used to compare if they are the same.

`image1` and `image2` change as we go along the search. So it changes the index.

If my [compare()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/39987/34844) method returns a true, it will delete the second image.

However, on the `compare()` method, I seem to be getting this exception error on this line:

```
BitmapData bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
```

Comment: Show us a complete reproducable code

Comment: @AlvinWong It's on the link I posted (Code Review) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39980/is-there-a-faster-way-to-compare-if-2-images-are-the-same/39987#39987

Comment: Have you locked the bits somewhere but forgot to call UnlockBits?

Comment: @AlvinWong On the bottom of the code of the method it would say `bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);`
`bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);` And I believe that exception came on the 2nd part of the method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, actually it took me quite a while to notice this line:

```
if (compare(image2, image2))
```

You are passing the same `Bitmap` to the function `compare`, so when the function attempts to call `LockBits` on the same `Bitmap` twice, this exception occurs.

So in order to fix it, don't pass the same bitmaps to the function.