# Change resolution of jpeg image using c#

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, imaging

I am trying to change resolution of my jpg image using c#.
I have refer this code that written in this link [How to change resolution (DPI) of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427059/how-to-change-resolution-dpi-of-an-image) its work fine but I have getting another issue for grayscale images.
if I will try to save grayscale image using this code then it change the bit depth 8 to 24.

So I have try below code but I am getting error like "Bitmap region is already locked". I don't know how to pass guid in GetEncoderParameterList().

```
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {

        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();

        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

   //Code
   using (Image bitmap = Image.FromFile(pagePath))
        {
            using (Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap))
            {
                ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                EncoderParameters para = newBitmap.GetEncoderParameterList(jpgEncoder.Clsid);
                imageResolution = (int)newBitmap.HorizontalResolution;
                newBitmap.SetResolution(250, 250);
                newBitmap.Save("file300.jpg", jpgEncoder, para);
            }
        }
```

Exception :

[image]

Comment: can you please edit your question to include the exact `exception` thrown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected "Bitmap Region is already Locked" exception with GetEncoderParameterList. Any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152506/unexpected-bitmap-region-is-already-locked-exception-with-getencoderparameterl)

Comment: @AccessDenied I have try this one but its give me another exception like  "File not found"

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346211/bitmap-region-is-already-locked

Comment: I am not comparing images. I am try to change resolution of image and save it. but when I try to save gray-scale images its change automatically to RGB. so I am try to assigning same encode parameter for gray-scale but it throws an error.

Comment: I can confirm this bug.

Comment: Not all __defined__ pixelformats are actually __supported__. 24bit grayscale is not. Not all GDI+ error messages are to the points. This may not be..

Comment: 8-bit jpeg does not exist on GDI+ and gets converted to 24-bit on load. If all you want to do is edit the EXIF data, I suggest you look into the EXIF specs and parse the binary format to edit it.

Comment: @TaW no, they said their 8-bit grayscale gets converted to 24-bit, which is normal RGB.